# From where in Android source code do they download the kernel?

Tags: android, kernel

I am trying to delve myself into the android source code, and I realized that Android source code do not contain pre-compiled kernels for many devices (such as Samsung toro, etc).

So, I presume that Android download necessary kernels as they are built, but I can't find the code where they actually perform kernel downloads.

I found few relevant files such as "generate-factory-images-package.sh" or "generate-packages.sh", but they do not seem to perform actual downloading process.

Can someone point me toward the code where Android actually fetch necessary kernels?

Thank you!

Comment: If something needs to be fetched, those are binary blobs for driver modules. You compile against an architecture of a device.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more? I am a newbie to Android :3

Comment: ROM uses kernel. Kernel uses modules for drivers. Some of the modules needs to be downloaded as they are not Open Source. Make sure you understand relation between kernel and modules. Right now it seems you want to compile a kernel while downloading kernel. Head over to XDA for countless tutorials on compiling ROMs and kernels. Many people are not specifically devs of software but have hands on experience in compiling either ROMs or kernels. For more specific, code related, knowledge better visit here.